# Column name condition when dynamically binding grid in knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I am having the following `tbody` with dynamic rows and columns:

```
 <tbody data-bind="foreach: ClientListingData">
        <tr>
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.OrderedColumns -->
            <!-- if: $parent[OrderedColumns] == 'ClientID' -->
            <td class="greenbg">
                <span data-bind="text:  $parent[$data]"></span>
            </td>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- if: $parent != 'ClientId' -->
            <td>
                <span data-bind="text:  $parent[$data]"></span>
            </td>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

`ClientListingData` contains the entire grid data in JSON format and `OrderedColumns` is an array object containing the column name like `[ClientID,ClientName..etc]` Which I am usng to dynamically bind my grid. My requirement is when the column name is `ClientID` I want `td` to have a different `css` class which I am trying to above. How can I read the name of the column using the `if` binding and do something using the `OrderedColumns` array? Also is it possible to nest conditions using `if` binding in my example?Like if the `ClientID` is greater than 10, I want the td to have orange background and if it is greater than 100, the td should have red background.

Answer (score 1):

There's a binding specifically for CSS

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html

```
<div data-bind="css: { profitWarning: currentProfit() < 0 }">
   Profit Information
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        currentProfit: ko.observable(150000) // Positive value, so initially we don't apply the "profitWarning" class
    };
    viewModel.currentProfit(-50); // Causes the "profitWarning" class to be applied
</script>
```

Comment: this is for applying different CSS classes based on an observable value but what to use when I want to render completely different markup based on some condition. For example using the KO `if` binding give different `HTML` markup as I have posted in my question?

Comment: As you say, if you want different mark-up based on a condition, use an if. If you want different css, apply a class using the css binding. Yes you can also nest if's. If you create a js fiddle, i'll have a look at fixing it.